# Solving 502 Bad Gateway Error for a Django Project Nginx - gunicorn - Debian

Tags: django, linux, nginx, debian, gunicorn

Hi I am trying to deploy my Django Project to Production for the first time using Nginx and gunicorn on linode.

Currently I did not set a venv file I just downloaded all the requirements in the system as a whole.
I am using Linode Server and selected Django from the market place and the set system is Debian.
The project was working perfectly well with portal 8000 but now I am trying to take it to development.

I have made the following steps:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service for project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/DjangoApp/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can't find the sock file in the project but this is the tree of the project if it helps cd /var/www/DjangoApp:

```
api  db.sqlite3  project  manage.py  media  README.md  requirements.txt  static  tac  users
```

in the /var/www/DjangoApp/project

```
asgi.py  __init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

in my sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/project

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 111.111.111.11;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /var/www/DjangoApp/;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock;
        }
}
```

here is the log error

```
root@139-177-193-82:~# sudo tail -50 /var/log/nginx/error.log
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * open socket #11 left in connection 4                                                                                  ...........
......................: * open socket #13 left in connection 6                                                                                  ...........
......................: aborting                                                                                                                ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,.........................
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
......................: * connect() to unix:/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, ...........
```

My question:
Where can I find the .sock file to connect to it to fix this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated to find solution to fix 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Your sock file is not created becouse of nginx giving you error about it fails to connect it so to debug you've check status of your service file run this command `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service` check waht you see there if you see any error related application then fix that error

Comment: If there is not error and status shows active then stop yout service `sudo systemctl stop gunicorn.service` and after this start it again `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.service`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari it was active before but now it failed `can't connect to `/var/www/DjangoApp/project.sock` . I also can't find the file itself however `gunicorn --bind 111.111.111.11:8000 project.wsgi` is working

Comment: now when I typed `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn && systemctl status gunicorn` it is showing as active and running

Comment: I tried `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.service` but still showing same error

Comment: Hello @A_K first stop your service and then start it and enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating the service file you need to create **systemd Socket** that in turn create the **sock** file, to do that you need to create a file under `/etc/systemd/system/<file name you want>` like the following.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_django_app.socket
```

in that file you need to provide the following details

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service for project

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn_django_app.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

This will create a sock file under **/run/gunicorn_django_app.sock**

Then you need to create a **systemd service file** in the path `/etc/systemd/system/<file name you like>`
like the following

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_django_app.service
```

In the file you need to provide service related details

```
[Unit]
 Description=gunicorn daemon
 Requires=gunicorn_django_app.socket
 After=network.target

[Service]
  User=username # user that can access those files
  Group=www-data # group that can access those files 
  WorkingDirectory=<projectpath>
  ExecStart=/<guincorn path>\
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn_django_app \
      DjangoApp.wsgi:application
```

then you have to start the services

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn_django_app.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn_django_app.socket
```

to know more use the below link this will help you to understand more on this concepts. it's in ubuntu linux but debain based linux (it will work on Linode too)
[digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: to check the sock file working fine you can use the below command in terminal ```curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn_django_app localhost```